# how to pass data from tableview to tableview like instagram? swift

Tags: ios, swift

If users search, the results come out on first table View(searchHome).
And If I select one cell, I can see detail info of this on to next tableView(bookDetail).
So in bookDetail, so only one cell exists like instagram.(it's like instagram my page. In my page I can see many pictures, but I select one, I can only 1 picture with detail info).

but the data of searchHome is not passed to the detailBook.

there are 3 classes with this issue.
One is class for passing data(BookAPIResult)
Another is class of UITableViewController for search(SearchHome)
The other is class of UITableViewController for detailIndo(bookDetail)

```
class BookAPIresult {


// thumbnail url
var thumbnail : String?

// book title
var title : String?

// book author
var author : String?

// book pub.
var pubnm : String?

// book description
var description : String?

// sellerID
var seller : String?

// list Price
var listPrice : String?

// selling Price
var sellPrice : String?

// UIImage for Thumbnail
var thumbnailImage : UIImage?

}
```

and SearchHome class is below.

```
class SearchHome: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate{

 // MARK: - Properties
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
// var barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Search", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)

let apiKey : String = "cbccaa3f2e893c245785c3b94d980b0c"

var searchString : String = ""



var list = Array<BookAPIresult>()


// MARK: - View Setup
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.searchController.delegate = self

    //self.searchController.searchBar.text! = ""

    //Setup the status bar
    tableView.contentInset.top = 0



    // Setup the Search Controller
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Prominent
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    //searchController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
    // Setup the Scope Bar
    searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Title", "HashTag"]
    //tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar


    // Setup Animation for NavigationBar
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    navigationController?.hidesBarsWhenKeyboardAppears = false
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
    navigationController?.hidesBarsWhenVerticallyCompact = true

    self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SearchHome.handleRefresh(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    // declare hide keyboard swipe
    let hideSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SearchHome.hideKeyboardSwipe(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(hideSwipe)


   // searchController.searchBar.text = searchString
}



func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar){

    self.searchString = self.searchController.searchBar.text!

    self.list.removeAll()

    self.callBookAPI()

    self.tableView.reloadData()

    self.searchController.active = false

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.searchController.active = false
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.list.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let row = self.list[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ListCell") as! BookAPIResultCell

    cell.title?.text = row.title
    cell.author?.text = row.author

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ cell.thumb.image = self.getThumbnailImage(indexPath.row)})


    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    NSLog("%d 행을 눌렀음",indexPath.row)

    var bookInfo = BookAPIresult()

    let row = self.list[indexPath.row]

    bookInfo.title = row.title
    bookInfo.author = row.author
    bookInfo.thumbnail = row.thumbnail
    bookInfo.pubnm = row.pubnm
    bookInfo.listPrice = row.listPrice
    bookInfo.sellPrice = ""
    bookInfo.seller = "nobody"
    bookInfo.description = row.description

    //detailVeiw instance
    let postInfo = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("detailBook") as! detailBook
    postInfo.navigationItem.title = bookInfo.title
    postInfo.bookDetail.append(bookInfo)

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(postInfo, animated: true)

}



override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.view.endEditing(false)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func callBookAPI(){

    let encodedSearchString = searchString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let apiURI = NSURL(string: "https://apis.daum.net/search/book?apikey=\(self.apiKey)&q=\(encodedSearchString!)&searchType=title&output=json")

    let apidata : NSData? = NSData(contentsOfURL: apiURI!)


    NSLog("API Result = %@", NSString(data: apidata!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)


    do {

        let data = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(apidata!, options:[]) as! NSDictionary

        let channel = data["channel"] as! NSDictionary
      //  NSLog("\(data)")
        let result = channel["item"] as! NSArray

        var book : BookAPIresult

        for row in result {

            book = BookAPIresult()

            let title = row["title"] as? String
            book.title = title

            if let authorEx = row["author"] as? String{
                book.author = authorEx
            }else{
                book.author = ""
            }

            if let pubEX = row["pub_nm"] as? String{
                book.pubnm = pubEX
            }else{
                book.pubnm = ""
            }

            if let listEX = row["list_price"] as? String{
                book.listPrice = "\(listEX)dollar"
            }else{
                book.listPrice = "0"
            }

            if let thunmbEX = row["cover_s_url"] as? String{
                book.thumbnail = thunmbEX
            }else{
                book.thumbnail = ""
            }

            //NSLog("\(book.thumbnail)")
            if let description = row["description"] as? String{
                if let decodedDescription = description.stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding){
                    book.description = decodedDescription
                }else{
                    book.description = ""
                }

            }else{
                 book.description = ""
            }


            self.list.append(book)
        }

        } catch {

            NSLog("parse error")

        }

}

func getThumbnailImage(index : Int) -> UIImage {

    let book = self.list[index]

    if let savedImage = book.thumbnailImage {
        return savedImage
    } else {

        if book.thumbnail == "" {

            book.thumbnailImage = UIImage(named:
                "Book Shelf-48.png")
        }else{

            let url = NSURL(string: book.thumbnail!)

            let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

            book.thumbnailImage = UIImage(data:imageData!)
        }

        return book.thumbnailImage!
    }
}

func handleRefresh(refreshControl:UIRefreshControl){

    self.searchString = self.searchController.searchBar.text!

    self.list.removeAll()

    self.callBookAPI()

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}



override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return false
}

}

extension SearchHome: UISearchResultsUpdating {
// MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating Delegate
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
    let scope = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]
 //   filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!, scope: scope)
}
}
```

And the last is detailBook.

```
class detailBook : UITableViewController {

var bookDetail = Array<BookAPIresult>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = false
    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsWhenVerticallyCompact = false
    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false


    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    let backBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "뒤로가기", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "back:")
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBtn

    //swipe to back
    let backSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "back:")
    backSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(backSwipe)

    //dynamic cell height
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 620



}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //define cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! detailBookCell

    let row = self.bookDetail[indexPath.row]

    cell.author.text = row.author
    cell.pubnm.text = row.pubnm
    cell.listPrice.text = row.listPrice
    cell.sellPrice.text = row.sellPrice
    cell.detailInfo.text = row.description
    cell.detailInfo.sizeToFit()

    let url = NSURL(string: row.thumbnail!)
    let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    cell.bookImage.image = UIImage(data:imageData!)

    return cell
}

//back button
func back(recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        bookDetail.removeAll()
}
}
```

Comment: After postInfo.bookDetail.append(bookInfo) in SearchHome, 0 values is in bookDetail(Array) of detailBook Class.

Answer (score 0):

You array, bookDetail, in the detailBlock class is still nil, so appending will not add any elements. You should first initialize a new array, add your bookInfo item to it, then assign detailBook's bookDetail item to this new array.

Comment: could you tell me how ans where I initialize ?

Comment: You would create a new array in DidSelectRowAtIndexPath after you instantiate the view controller from the storyboard. Then add your bookInfo object to it, then assign postInfo.bookDetail equal to this new array. But also, may I ask why you are using an array in this situation? It seems that you are only passing one instance of you BookApi object. You could just have a bookAPI property on your detailBook controller and assign that to your bookInfo that you create in DidSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the prepareForSegue method in your search view controller and then use performSequeWithIdentifier in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Basically, set up a placeholder object in the bookDetail view controller. In the search view controller set the value of a global object based in didSelecRowAtIndexPath and use the prepareForSegue method to set the placeholder object with the one you just set on your search view controller. When you select a row and it calls the performSegueWithIdentifier method, it will automatically call prepareForSegue and pass the value to the new view controller.